# Use typeof Window.chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I installed this NPM package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chrome

Right now I have this in my code:

```
declare var chrome;

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  console.log('extension is connected to port:', port);
  port.onMessage.addListener(function (msg) {
    console.log('message from port:', msg);
  });
});
```

when I get rid of the declare statement, my IDE (Webstorm) doesn't give me any suggestions for which type to use.

**Does anyone know how to properly reference/incorporate the chrome typings in a project?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install the chrome definitions.

```
npm install @types/chrome --save-dev
```

Then, reference it in one of your typescript files. I do it in my `custom-typings.d.ts`

```
///<reference types="chrome"/>

...
```